# is there something like 'with_indifferent_access' for arrays usable for include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to only use :symbols for key words in my app. I try to strict decide between :symbol => logic or string => UI/language specific

But I get some "values" (ie. options and so on) per JSON, too, since there are no :symbols in JSON, all my invoked hashes have the "with_indifferent_access" attribute.

but: is there something equal for array? like that

```
a=['std','elliptic', :cubic].with_indifferent_access

a.include? :std => true
```

?

edit: added rails to tags

Comment: That is in Rails, I think with Hash. But in pure Ruby, no nothing like that present..

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. You need to improve the wording.

Comment: Does it help? http://rubydoc.info/github/cpence/rletters/Array#with_indifferent_access-instance_method

Comment: @ArupRakshit: yes! my fault, it happens to me from time to time to mixup ruby and rails

Comment: You might also be interested in the `symbolize_keys: true` option of `JSON.parse`: [http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ['std','elliptic', :cubic].map(&:to_sym)
a.include? :std
#=> true
```

Edit - regarding the comment by maxigs probably better to convert to strings:

```
a = ['std', 'elliptic', :cubic].map(&:to_s)
a.include? "std"
#=> true
```

Comment: yes, sure, *getting red*, i will use your answer, to map the arrays I get to my (internal standard) hashes. (`a={std:true, ....}`)

Comment: `['std','elliptic', :cubic].any?{|e| e.to_sym == :std}` would be more efficient.

Comment: Little note: Carefull when using to_sym on dynamic data. Symbols are not ever getting cleaned out of memory by the garbage collector. This might lead to endlessly growing memory of the process (aka. a memory leak)

Comment: As a side note, in most recent Ruby versions they are, so now it's perfectly fine to use both approaches

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr

```
['std','elliptic', :cubic].flat_map { |s| [s.to_sym, s.to_s] }
```

---

Many times with Rails, I'll have a validation of inclusion in array. I, too, like to work with symbols. It might look something like this:

```
validates :source, inclusion: { in: [:source1, :source2] }
```

And that might be valid when I first create the object with a symbol, but becomes invalid when it reads `source` from the db and returns a string. I could monkey-patch the getters to always return symbols, but I'd rather not. Instead, I do:

```
validates :source, inclusion: { in: [:source1, :source2].flat_map { |s| [s, s.to_s] } }
```